# Inconsistent synchronization

Tags: c#, synchronization, resharper

A public method of an `abstract class` starts with a lock on a static object. Several small private functions are called, some of them using a member variable (and that member variable is only used in these private functions, nowhere else). Something like

```
private SomeType _SomeMember;
private static readonly object TheLock = new object();
public void DoSomething()
{
    lock(TheLock)
    {
        Step1();
        ...
        Step5();
        ...
        Step9();
}
private void Step5()
{
    ...
    _SomeMember.Blah();
    ...
}
```

Now I had to override `Step5()` in one of many derived classes. Means also that I had to change the signature to `protected virtual`.
And now ReSharper (version 10.0.2) started complaining about inconsistent synchronization, exactly where I use `_SomeMember` in `Step5()` in the base class (in the derived class, `Step5()` is empty):

```
ReSharper:
The field is sometimes used inside synchronized block and sometimes used without synchronization
```

I also noted that the warning appears when I make the function `protected` (without `virtual`), `internal` or `public`.

Since `Step5()` is only called from `DoSomething()`, it looks to me like a wrong warning. 
Or did I fail to see where the synchronization context gets lost?

Comment: Is solution-wide analysis enabled? It may be that ReSharper doesn't have sufficient context to assert that it *definitely isn't* called by a derived class, but the change in accessibility means that it now *can be*.

Comment: I think it refers to the fact that you can now call the method outside the the `Synchroised` block, and is warning you of this ability. You wouldn't if you used the base class (seems like template method to me)

Comment: @Charles Mager: Yes, solution wide analysis is enabled.

Comment: @CallumLinington I could do so, but I don't. Do you think that the wording of the message text is misleading?

Comment: Sort of, yes/no. `sometimes used` is sort of. But then again `it could be`. I would be a bit annoyed at the message showing up and reluctant to use Resharper Disable once stuff....